# Should we advertise when vote close as non reproductible when it's only a typo

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[how to link 2 or more images one after the other, having the same dimensions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445838/how-to-link-2-or-more-images-one-after-the-other-having-the-same-dimensions)
This question might get close because it's only a typo, but I found sometime question on the site where the mention of a typo appears only in the comment way down.
Nothing is explicit about that while you fell having the same question as the OP and it's not because it's only a typo.

I feel like the mention

> or went away when a typo was fixed

on closed question should be emphasis as no one really read small lines and the mention : it's `not reproducible` is much broader than just typo IMHO (and Typos are reproducible).
Should we just correct the typo and answer instead and insist on the fact it's only a typo not a real problem ?

Comment: I guess the idea is not to have one question for "every possible" typo.

Answer (score 4):

There are two main purposes for Stack Exchange sites:

- help someone solve a specific problem (or more generally, answer a specific question);
- help others with similar problems.

The second is captured more ambitiously in [the tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) as “With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Unix or Linux.”

I tend to think of the “problem can’t be reproduced” close reason as useful for questions which only serve the first purpose above (insofar as we can determine that). These questions, typo questions in particular, only need sufficient feedback for the asker to figure out what the typo was; once that’s fixed, there’s nothing further to fix and the answer is unlikely to be useful to anyone else. Keeping these questions (and answers, even if only in comments) only adds to the noise on the site.

I agree that the close reason could perhaps be rephrased. When I see

> "Questions describing **a problem that can't be reproduced** and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers."

I think of it as two entirely different reasons:

- problems which can’t be reproduced (with the possible reason that they went away on their own, which sometimes is nice if only to “save face”) — I get the impression we don’t actually use this all that often, in part I think because it discounts the asker’s experience which we assume is true (even if their account of it is flawed);
- typos, which obviously can be reproduced but are “unlikely to help future readers”.

Perhaps a better phrasing would be

> “Questions describing a problem that **can’t be reproduced** (and seemingly went away on its own) or that **can be fixed by correcting a typo** are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers.”

As for how to deal with such questions, I think that pointing out the typo in comments is fine, for multiple reasons. The asker will presumably be sufficiently invested in fixing the problem that they’ll take the time to read the comments and find the typo; that addresses your point that “the mention of a typo appears only in the comment way down” (it also helps if people delete their obsolete comments, or flag others’ for moderator intervention). Writing up a proper answer for a typo would be counter-productive, because answers here tend to collect upvotes reasonably quickly if they’re correct, and upvoted answers [prevent questions from being deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Comment: I could agree on the phrasing, my feeling is that I often find question close from google because i use the same terms as in the question. So it's either me not looking for the right answer either the question use by the OP which was confusing. Couldn't we agree somehow to try to rephrase question so it's obvious it's a typo though I understand it would be hard to maintain

Comment: I almost agree with this, except that "typos" itself breaks down into two *completely* distinct categories: (1) typos where the person did not type the exact sequence of symbols they intended to type, and (2) typos where the person didn't realize that a small difference in symbols was actually important, such as using `if ["$a" -gt 3]` in bash.  The difference is that answering the second category of "typo" **IS** likely to help future readers.